# Will changes on the hosts file affect iframes loading on remote computers?

Tags: linux, iframe

Consider this:

facebook.com - IP: 1.1.1.1
My server's IP: 2.2.2.2

On my server, if put this on my /etc/hosts file:

```
2.2.2.2 facebook.com
```

And try to access facebook.com on my server, instead of loading facebook.com from Facebook's servers, the browser will try to find facebook.com on my server.

This is a local setup.

Now let's say I host a page on my server with the following line:

```
<iframe src="http://facebook.com/" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>
```

If I try to access this page from my server, the browser will try to find the domain on 2.2.2.2, because of the hosts file.

Now, if a user with an untouched hosts file access this same page, will their browser load facebook.com from 1.1.1.1, or from 2.2.2.2?

Server is using Apache 2.4, CentOS 6.5.

Answer (score 0):

All URLs in documents are resolved by the client computer. The hosts file on the server is irrelevant. So if the user has a regular hosts file, they'll go to the real facebook.com.